# What is a good design for this situation?

Tags: c++, direct3d

I am making a basic render engine.

In order to let the render engine operate on all kinds of geometry,
I made this class:

```
class Geometry
{
protected:
ID3D10Buffer* m_pVertexBuffer;
ID3D10Buffer* m_pIndexBuffer;

public:
[...]
};
```

Now, I would like the user to be able to create his own geometry by inheriting from this class.
So let's suppose the user made a `class Cube : public Geometry`
The user would have to create the vertexbuffer and indexbuffer at initialisation.

This is a problem, since it would recreate the vertexbuffer and indexbuffer each time a new Cube object is made. There should only be one instance of vertexbuffer and indexbuffer per derived class. Either that, or a completely different design.

A solution might be to make separate `static ID3D10Buffer*` for the inheriting class , and set the pointers of the inherited class equal to those in the constructor.

But that would require a static method like `static void CreateBuffers()` which the user would have to call explicitly one time in his application for each type he decides to make that inherits from `Geometry`. That doesn't seem like a nice design.

What is a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Why is recreating the buffers a problem? Do you not want one set per object?

Comment: is your requirement :
1. You want only one INSTANCE of vertex buffer and index buffer for each inherited class 
OR 
2. You want to create the buffers for each object at a later point of time, not at the time of creation of the object?

Comment: @Unni I only want to create one instance of the vertex buffer and index buffer for each inherited class

Comment: this problem has some similarity with the singleton pattern. does this help? ;)

Comment: @tzaman : Because that would be insanely slow, imagine you would have a thousand cubes in a scene, you would create thousands of cube objects and would recreate the same buffer thousands of times...
The goal is to create one instance of vertex buffer and index buffer per derived class

Comment: @yi_H I don't know, can/should I create a singleton for each derived class but not for the base class?

Comment: You should separate the concept of an instance from the concept of a mesh. This means you create one version of the Geometry for a cube that represents the vertex and index buffer for a cube. You then introduce a new class called GeometryInstance which contains a transformation matrix. This class should have a pointer/reference to a Geometry. Now you can create new Instances of your geometry by creating GeometryInstances that all refer the same Geometry object not duplicating memory or work when creating a new box

Comment: @Laserallan: That really should be an answer rather than a comment :)

Comment: @Laserallan I have a Mesh class which contains a pointer to the geometry, transformation matrix and some other stuff, I even have classes on top of that. But I don't really understand what you're trying to say, could you write a little pseudocode in an answer?

Comment: Please rephrase your title to clarify what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 4):

You should separate the concept of an instance from the concept of a mesh. This means you create one version of the Geometry for a cube that represents the vertex and index buffer for a cube.

You then introduce a new class called GeometryInstance which contains a transformation matrix. This class should also have a pointer/reference to a Geometry. Now you can create new Instances of your geometry by creating GeometryInstances that all refer the same Geometry object not duplicating memory or work when creating a new box.

EDIT: 
Given that you have the Geometry class from the question and a Mesh class as in your comment your Mesh class should look something like this:

```
class Mesh {
  private:
  Matrix4x4 transformation;
  Geometry* geometry;
  public:
  Mesh(const Matrix4x4 _t, Geometry* _g) : transformation(_t), geometry(_g) {}
}
```

Now when creating your scene you want to do things like this

```
...
std::vector<Mesh> myMeshes;
// OrdinaryGeometry is a class inheriting Geometry 
OrdinaryGeometry* geom = new OrdinaryGeometry(...);
for(int i = 0; i < ordinaryGeomCount; ++i) {
  // generateTransform is a function that generates some 
  // transformation Matrix given an index, just as an example
  myMeshes.push_back(Mesh(generateTransform(i), geom);
}
// SpecialGeometry is a class inheriting Geometry with a different
// set of vertices and indices
SuperSpecialGeometry* specialGeom = new SuperSpecialGeometry(...);
for(int i = 0; i < specialGeomCount; ++i) {
  myMeshes.push_back(Mesh(generateTransform(i), specialGeom);
}

// Now render all instances
for(int i = 0; i < myMeshes.size(); ++i) {
  render(myMeshes[i]);
}
```

Note how we only have two Geometry objects that are shared between multiple Meshes. These should ideally be refcounted using std::shared_ptr or something similar but it's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: You do have a point there, and I thought of something likewise. However the question arises what to do when you share these between classes. It's hard to put it into words like this so I'll give an example.
For example, you make a class 'Ball', which has a sphere geometry, and some physics and stuff added.
In your scene you want a thousand Balls. No problem, we can handle that by making the sphere geometry a static member of the Ball class.
But! The user also has a class Rocket, which for some obscure reason also needs a sphere geometry. How would you solve this without having two instances?

Comment: I don't think making the SphereGeometry a static member of Ball is a good idea. I think it's better to make sure your Ball instances finds the SphereGeometry in a different way, maybe by asking a factory for it that only generates a sphere the first time you ask for it and then return the same copy if it's already there. This design will also allow your rocket to ask your factory for the same SphereGeometry and you will share the instance.

Comment: A factory could work, only for this case I think it's a bad design:
The factory would be a part of the engine, and I don't think allowing the client to mess with the engine is good design. (He would have to because he is allowed to make new classes derived from geometry)

I think singleton might be my only solution here, although it's very messy since I need to pass an extra member (ID3DDevice*) to either GetInstance(), or make an additional Initialise(ID3DDevice*) method, which would also be very sloppy...

I'm out of ideas, can you still help?

Comment: I don't know if I can give much more help here. One way of doing it would be to let the client to register their own creation methods in the factory for sharing purposes. A Singleton would totally work, it's not a solution that tend to scale to multiple types of objects but then again, why bother if it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 2):

What would be the point of sub classing Geometry in your cube example? A cube is simply an instance of Geometry which has a certain set of triangles and indices. There would be no difference between a Cube class and a Sphere class, other than that they fill their triangle/index buffers with different data. So the data itself is what is important here. You need a way to allow the user to provide your engine with various shape data, and to then refer to that data in some way once its made.

For providing shape data, you have two options. You can decide to either keep the details of Geometry private, and provide some interface that takes raw data like a string from a file, or a float array filled in some user made function, creates a Geometry instance for that data, and then gives the user some handle to that instance (or allow the user to specify a handle). Or, you can create some class like GeometryInfo which has methods addTriangle, addVertex etc which the user fills him/herself, and then have some function that accepts a GeometryInfo, creates a Geometry instance for that data and then gives the user some handle again.

In both situations you need to provide some interface that allows the user to say "here's some data, make something out of it and give it some handle. Minimally it would have a function as I described. You would need to maintain a map somewhere of created Geometry instances in your engine. This is so you enforce your one instance per shape rule, and so you can associate what the user wants ("Ball", "Cube") with what your engine needs (Geometry with filled buffers).

Now about the handle. I would either let the user associate the data with a name, like "Ball", or return some integer that the user would then associate with a certain "Ball" instance. That way when you make your Rocket class, the user can then request the "Ball" instance from your engine, various other objects can use the "Ball" and everything's fine because they're just storing handles, not the ball itself. I wouldn't advise storing a pointer to the actual Geometry instance. The mesh doesn't own the geometry, because it can share it with other meshes. It doesn't need access to the geometry's members, because the renderer handles the grunt work. So it is an unnecessary dependency. The only reason would be for speed, but using hashing for your handles would work just as good.

Now for some examples:

Providing shape data:

```
//option one
engine->CreateGeometryFromFile("ball.txt", "Ball");

//option two
GeometryInfo ball;

ball.addTriangle(0, 1, 0, 1);
ball.addTriangle(...);
...

engine->CreateGeometryFromInfo(ball, "Ball");
```

Refering to that data using a handle:

```
class Drawable
{
    std::string shape;
    Matrix transform;
};

class Rocket : public Drawable
{
    Rocket() { shape = "Ball";}
    //other stuff here for physics maybe
};

class BallShapedEnemy : public Drawable
{

    BallShapedEnemy() { shape = "Ball";}
    ...
}

...

...in user's render loop...

for each (drawable in myDrawables)
{
    engine->Render(drawable.GetShape(), drawable.GetTransform());
}
```

Now, having a separate class for each different game object such as Rocket is debatable, and is the subject of another question entirely, I was just making it look like your example from a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't like your suggestion to store handles though, why would you slow down the core algorithms of your engine to provide a little better design? I could just make the Geometry* a private member and/or even a const Geometry* if the user shouldn't fiddle with the Geometry.
Other than that, I thought about something like that, using a map, and you would be able to load it by proving a string.
However, let's assume the client has about 200 different geometries. He would either need to write down all the names he stored it with or remember all of them.

Comment: Do you know any solutions to that problem?

Comment: The thing is, looking up a string in a map really isn't going to slow you down compared to the heavy stuff (actually rendering, simulating etc). And if you later profiled it and saw that it had some impact, you could switch to a hash map. Or your handles could just be integers which represent the index of some array that stores all the geometries. Constant time lookup, same deal. The point is that it makes your job really easy, and tailoring it to perform better is easy. 200 geometries thing in next comment...

Comment: Now in the case of 200 different geometries, the user is probably going to be making them in some editor instead of doing all 200 by hand. That editor will save the geometry with some name, and then when the user fills a level with game objects, they would pick some shape from a list in the editor. The level's file would then contain an entry for each game object, which would contain the name of the shape from the editor. Now instead of hardcoding the names in the code, you would just process the files, do CreateGeometryXXX with the vertex data and shape name from a Shape.txt file, and ...

Comment: then you could have a general GameObject class, make a new instance for each game object in the Level.txt file, and then set the Shape member to be whatever value is in the file. The user would not have to handle the names manually, as the toolchain would take care of everything.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a sloppy way of doing it but could you not just make a singleton?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#define GEOM Geometry::getInstance()

class Geometry
{
protected:
    static Geometry* ptrInstance;
    static Geometry* getInstance();

    float* m_pVertexBuffer;
    float* m_pIndexBuffer;
public:
    Geometry(void);
    ~Geometry(void);

    void callGeom();
};

#include "Geometry.h"

Geometry* Geometry::ptrInstance = 0;

Geometry::Geometry(void)
{
}


Geometry::~Geometry(void)
{
}

Geometry* Geometry::getInstance()
{
    if(ptrInstance == 0)
    {
        ptrInstance = new Geometry();
    }
    return ptrInstance;
}

void Geometry::callGeom()
{
    std::cout << "Call successful!" << std::endl;
}
```

Only problem with this method is you would only ever have one Geometry object and I'm assuming you might want more than one? If not it could be useful, but I think Lasserallan's method is probably a much better implementation for what your looking for.

Comment: a singleton could be a solution, but not one like your example. Geometry doesn't need to be a singleton, in fact it may not be.
What could work is making the classes that derive from Geometry singletons, but I'm not sure if that is a clean way to handle it and if it is even possible, though it probably is

Comment: If it is done that way then I'm not so sure the classes that derive from Geometry as singletons would be a good idea as you could only have one of that specific type. I thought you were only after having a single instance of Geometry so I thought it might be easier to make it a singleton and have the objects you create inherit from that. But Laserallan's method seems like a much better implementation anyway so I'd probably go down their route. :D